# What is the difference between a Queue and a JoinableQueue in multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, queue

What is the difference between a Queue and a JoinableQueue in multiprocessing in Python? This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31230241/queue-vs-joinablequeue-in-python), but as some comments point out, the accepted answer is not helpful because all it does is quote the documentation. Could someone explain the difference in terms of when to use one versus the other? For example, why would one choose to use Queue over JoinableQueue if JoinableQueue is pretty much the same thing except for offering the two extra methods `join()` and `task_done()`. Additionally, the other answer in the post I linked to mentions that `Based on the documentation, it's hard to be sure that Queue is actually empty.` which again raises the question as to why would I want to use a Queue over JoinableQueue? What advantages does it offer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multiprocessing` patterns its queues off of `queue.Queue`. In that model, `Queue` keeps a "task count" of everything put on the queue. There are generally two ways to use this queue. Producers could just put things on the queue and ignore what happens to them in the long run. The producer may wait from time to time if the queue is full, but doesn't care if any of the things put on the queue are actually processed by the consumer. In this case the queue's task count grows, but who cares?

Alternately, the producer can "join" the queue. That means that it waits until the last task on the queue has been processed and the task count has gone to zero. But to do this, the producer needs the consumer's help. A consumer gets an item from the queue, but that doesn't decrease the task count. The consumer has to actively call `task_done` (typically when the task is done...) and the `join` will wait until every put has a task_done.

Fast forward to `multiprocessing`. The task_done mechanism requires communication between processes which is relatively expensive. If you are a type A producer that doesn't play the `join` game, use a `multiprocessing.Queue` and save a bit of CPU time. If you are a type B producer use `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue`. But remember that the consumer also has to play the task_done game or the producer will hang.